# android: reuse a RelativeLayout in XML by inflating it at run time?

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

Edition of question

It is already in a separate xml (tablet_shortterm_column.xml) see above.

Anyway, it seems logcat complains that rlo_shortterm_col already has a parent, so it won't allow an another ptr_rlo_rght_middle.addView(rlo_shortterm_col ).  Makes no sense.

---

I spent so many hours on thsi problem and still can't solve it.  Can someone please give me a hand? Thanks in advance.

I have an xml file (tablet_shortterm_column.xml) that contains a RelativeLayout that I need to re-use, again and again.  Sometimes many times on the same screen stacked one after the other horizontally.  I am attempting to insert one into an existing RelativeLayout (ie. one inside the other.)

//exerpts

```
public class TabletMain extends Activity {

       setContentView(R.layout.tablet_main);

      public RelativeLayout ptr_rlo_rght_middle;


      ptr_rlo_rght_middle = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlo_rght_middle); 
      //rlo_rght_middle is in tablet_main.xml


      LayoutInflater inflater = 
      (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
      View llo_tmp = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablet_shortterm_column,null);

      RelativeLayout rlo_tmp = (RelativeLayout) llo_tmp.findViewById(R.id.rlo_shortterm_col); 
    // rlo_shortterm_col is the object I want to reuse it a RelativeLayout and is inside 
    // tablet_shortterm_column.xml

       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlo_layoutparams;
       rlo_layoutparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( 
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 

       rlo_layoutparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.llo_rght_middle_col1); 
       // llo_rght_middle_col1 is a RelativeLayout inside tablet_main.xml,
       // I want to put another RelativeLayout view right next to it.

       rlo_tmp.setLayoutParams(rlo_layoutparams);

       ptr_rlo_rght_middle.addView(rlo_tmp);  //Application crashes right on this line.

} //end Activity
```

//*************************************** content of tablet_shortterm_column.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >
        <RelativeLayout 
                android:id="@+id/rlo_shortterm_col" 
                android:layout_width="180dp" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:background="#436699"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="3px" 
                android:weightSum="1"
            > <!-- android:background="#32CD32" android:layout_height="365dp" android:layout_margin="30px"  -->
                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/btn_shortterm_col"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Tuesday Afternoon" 
                    android:layout_margin="15px" 
                    android:textSize="12px"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
                    android:background="#296699"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                > <!--android:background="#32CD32"  -->
                </Button>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_shortterm_col"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_shortterm_col"
                    android:src="@drawable/tblet_icon14_med" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                ><!--  android:src="@drawable/tblet_shape1" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" -->
                </ImageView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_shortterm_col1" 
                    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_shortterm_col"
                    android:text="-10ºC" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10px"

                    android:background="#DCDCDC"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12px"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                > <!--  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" -->
                </TextView>
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/tv_shortterm_col2" 
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_shortterm_col1"
                    android:text="Flurries" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

                    android:layout_margin="10px"

                    android:background="#DCDCDC"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12px"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                >
                </TextView>
                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/rlo_shortterm_col_1" 
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_shortterm_col2"
                    android:src="@drawable/tblet_shape2"
                    android:background="#32CD32" 
                    android:layout_height="113dp"
                    android:layout_margin="40px" 
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                > <!--android:background="#32CD32"  android:orientation="vertical"  -->
                </RelativeLayout>           
            </RelativeLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make different xml for relativeLayout that is common to all layouts and inflate it

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate xml file for your RelativeLayout and then inflate it as many times as you want.

Comment: It is already in a separate xml (tablet_shortterm_column.xml) see above.

Anyway, it seems logcat complains that rlo_shortterm_col already has a parent, so it won't allow an another ptr_rlo_rght_middle.addView(rlo_shortterm_col ).  Makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

llo_tmp is the parent view of the `RelativeLayout` you're trying to reuse.  Thus, you can't add it to another `ViewGroup` and you get that logcat error.

You can remove the `LinearLayout` stuff from your xml file and inflate the xml file in the same way (though maybe instead of returned `View` you'd return a `RelativeLayout`).  You *shouldn't* have to change much of the java code since the reference is still the same.

Or, a quick fix may be to add llo_tmp to your `ViewGroup` instead of rlo_tmp.  Either way, rlo_tmp already has a parent and can't be reused.  Since you don't have your layout fill the entire screen width, you probably don't want this.

Comment: The LinaerLayout was added to the xml file by default when I used Eclipse to create a new xml file.  Afterwards I inserted the RelativeLayout into this file (tablet_shortterm_column.xml).  It's this RelativeLayout that I need to reuse again and again.  I don't need the LinearLayout wrapper at all.  I didn't know you an just strip it out as it has that funny line "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: That line is required at the top view so that the reader can interpret the attributes (anything with "android:").  You can put that line in anything.  You can move that line to the RelativeLayout and remove the LinearLayout and it should compile.

Comment: Oh My God!   That worked!   Thanks DeeV.  I was up till 2am last night trying to get this damn thing to work!  :-(